# how to make a bot be active on your pc even if ur pc is turned off

Tags: bots

i created a bot to get the latest updates on a particular interest of mine from the web however it stops doing it when i power off my pc, is there a way to make it run even when i turned my pc off?

i feel like i need to upload it to the web or smth but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If your PC is turned off, then nothing will be running on it. What you are trying to achieve is similar to watching a movie on a turned off TV.

What you want is a server, which is a PC but you never turn it off. If you really want to go straight to the point, you could just install a linux distro on a any old computer you have. Run the bot on it and don't turn it off.

Now, it seems you are a missing a bunch of knowledge on this topic. I strongly encourage you to research more on what is a server, what is a client-server architecture, how linux work and how to maintain a linux server, virtual machines and docker. I might be missing some, but that's rougthly what you need in order to have a basic comprehension to install & maintain a server. You could also host your bot online as you said.

It would really help if you could add more to your question on what is your knowledge on the subject ? What is the bot doing more precisely ?